# Does every triangle satisfy $\frac{1}{a-b+\pi R} + \frac{1}{b-c+\pi R} - \frac{1}{c-a+\pi R} < \frac{1}{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, algebra-precalculus, inequality, triangles

Experimental data show that in any triangle with sides $(a,b,c)$ and circumradius $R$, if $x > 2$ then,

$$
\frac{1}{x} - \frac{4}{x^2 - 4} < \frac{R}{a-b+Rx} + \frac{R}{b-c+Rx} - \frac{R}{c-a+Rx} 
< \frac{1}{x} + \frac{4}{x^2 - 4} \tag 1
$$

Can this be proved or disproved?

**Corollary**: Assuming the above upper bound is true, at $x = \pi$, the upper bound is $0.999787$ which is remarkably close to $1$ and thus we have

$$
\frac{1}{a-b+\pi R} + \frac{1}{b-c+\pi R} - \frac{1}{c-a+\pi R}
< \frac{1}{R} \tag 2
$$

[Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880812/in-a-triangle-if-p-left-frac1a-bx-frac1b-cx-ge-frac1c-ax-rig).